# How to install MySql on Ubuntu 10

Tags: ubuntu, installation, boot, mysql

I have done the following:

```
shell> sudo apt-get install mysql-server-core-5.1
shell> sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.1
```

Both seemed to complete fine with no errors. I have the following present:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld
```

However if I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 2)
```

for the simple reason that in fact this directory does not exist. Now the correct way to start the daemon is apparently:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

however this script does not seem to exist either. So has my install totally messed up, or is there a step I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try installing the packages `mysql-client` and `mysql-server` instead.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server
```

Comment: yes, all you need to do is mysql-server and everything is set up. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put `sudo` before running `/usr/sbin/mysqld` command.